# RegEx required to capture full word, space and • symbol in all instances within a varaible selection of text

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I need to be able to select variable elements from the following ingredient list example.

I wish to collect the 'full word, space & •' in all instances.

```
INGREDIENTS: ALCOHOL DENAT. • FRAGRANCE (PARFUM) • WATER\AQUA\EAU • HYDROXYCITRONELLAL • LIMONENE • BENZYL BENZOATE • CITRONELLOL • GERANIOL • COUMARIN • FARNESOL • CITRAL • BENZYL ALCOHOL • CINNAMYL ALCOHOL • LINALOOL • ALCOHOL • DIPROPYLENE GLYCOL • ETHYLHEXYL METHOXYCINNAMATE • BUTYL METHOXYDIBENZOYLMETHANE • ETHYLHEXYL SALICYLATE • TRIS(TETRAMETHYLHYDROXYPIPERIDINOL) CITRATE • DILAURYL THIODIPROPIONATE • TOCOPHEROL • BHT • BENZOIC ACID • RED 4 (CI 14700) • EXT. VIOLET 2 (CI 60730) • YELLOW 6 (CI 15985) <ILN46472>
```

I have `\b\w+\s•` but this is only selecting 'EAU •' within the copy, where as I need all instances within the list

```
DENAT. •
(PARFUM) •
EAU •
HYDROXYCITRONELLAL •
LIMONENE •
BENZOATE •
CITRONELLOL •
GERANIOL •
COUMARIN •
FARNESOL •
CITRAL •
ALCOHOL •
ALCOHOL •
LINALOOL •
ALCOHOL •
GLYCOL •
METHOXYCINNAMATE •
METHOXYDIBENZOYLMETHANE •
SALICYLATE •
CITRATE •
THIODIPROPIONATE •
TOCOPHEROL •
BHT •
ACID •
(CI 14700) •
(CI 60730) •
```

Comment: `\w+` won't match parentheses or backslashes. Try changing that to `[\w()\\]+`.

Comment: You'll need a different pattern to match multiple words inside parentheses. `\(.*?\)`

Comment: @Nick They only want the last word of multiple words, so `ALCOHOL DENAT.` should only return `DENAT.`. Except, apparently, when multiple words are in parens.

Comment: @Barmar ah I misinterpreted...

Comment: You can use the following regular expression (with the `g` flag set) with most regex engines: `(?:[A-Z]+\.?|\([A-Z]+ +\d+\)) +•`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ozASY/1). Hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function. I've assumed that one or more spaces may be present wherever there is one space in your example text. If exactly one space is to be matched change ` +` to just ` ` in two places. Incidentally, there is no reason to have so much repetition in your example. Best to make examples as tight as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those matches, you might use:

```
(?:\([^()]*\)|\w+\.?)\s•
```

The pattern matches

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\([^()]*\)` Match from `(....)`
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+\.?` Match 1+ word chars followed by an optional `.`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\s•` Match a whitespace char and `•`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6G0Qur/1)

If there has to be at least a word character in between the parenthesis:

```
(?:\([^\w()]*\w[^()]*\)|\w+\.?)\s•
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XW61Qq/1).

**Note** that `\w` can also match `_`

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been a huge help to me